# От каких корней произошли слова "пончо" и "епанча"?

Tags: этимология

Считается, что слово «пончо» заимствовано из кечуа или мапудунгун, а слово «епанча» происходит от тюркского слова. Эти слова созвучны и обозначают виды верхней одежды похожего кроя. Существует ли в русском языке слово, которое могло бы быть древней основой для образования слов «пончо» и «епанча»?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

1. Слово *пончо* пришло в испанский язык из языка индейцев-арауканов (мапуче), который считается языком-изолятом, т. е. не относится ни к одной из известных языковых семей.
2. Слово *епанча* — тюркизм (от тюркск. *япынджа*).
3. Ни в коем случае в русском языке (индоевропейской семьи!) не может быть корня, который дал бы жизнь одновременно тюркскому и арауканскому слову. Эти слова **этимологически не связаны**, и вообще такая связь практически невероятна.